# "Steps per sample" in DGM-Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am currently working with the Deep Galerkin Method and have looked at the code on the following Github account: https://github.com/adolfocorreia/DGM.
In his application of the Merton model https://github.com/adolfocorreia/DGM/blob/master/merton.py he codes:

```
# Train network!!
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

for i in range(sampling_stages):
    t1, x1, t2, x2, t3, x3 = sampler(NS_1, NS_2, NS_3)

    start_time = time.clock()
    for _ in range(steps_per_sample):
        loss, L1, L3, _ = sess.run([loss_t, L1_t, L3_t, optimizer],
                               feed_dict = {t1_t:t1, x1_t:x1, t2_t:t2, x2_t:x2, t3_t:t3, x3_t:x3})
    end_time = time.clock()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

    sampling_stages_list.append(i)
    elapsed_time_list.append(elapsed_time)
    loss_list.append(loss)
    L1_list.append(L1)
    L3_list.append(L3)
    
    text = "Stage: {:04d}, Loss: {:e}, L1: {:e}, L3: {:e}, {:f} seconds".format(i, loss, L1, L3, elapsed_time)
    print(text)
```

I have a simple question:
I do not understand the for-loop based on the steps per sample. As far as I understand we sample the set `{t1, x1, t2, x2, t3, x3}` for each epoch/sampling stage, but what dos the second loop do and why is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The sampling_stages correspond to the number of times you want to pick new samples and the steps_per_sample is the number of times you want to send each sample into the model. That's exactly what the second loop do, it run multiple time the same sample.

I assume that's a way to get faster result if sampling new data is very slow, and to take advantages of the Adam optimizer.